# ilog rule project reference and common variables

Tags: ilog

I am trying to create a rule project that will be used by few other rule projects. 
[The WODM document](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.designer.dev%2Fdeveloping_topics%2Ftsk_rulep_def_ruleproj_ref.html) only mentions that it makes the application modular.

Rule project A references Rule Project B. B is new and has no rules written so far.
My question is - 
 - The rule parameters are common for A and B. When I provided reference, I got '**unambigous parameter**' error. The error went off when I removed the parameters from B. Same is the case with local variables.

If this is how the setup needs to be done, how are these variables visible to B? If I add the reference to A, as expected, I get **cyclic reference error**. Can I change the preference to ignore this error? Is there any other way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Rule Project A references Rule Project B, can you have the rule parameters from A and have in B.

Also, it all depends on how you are planning/designing these rule projects to be used in the applications, like the dependencies, independent calls to the rule project A or B, etc.

Comment: I want to reuse Project B from within Project A and Project C. I tried including the ruleparameters of A (C has same rule parameters as A), but when I added reference to B (from Project A), I got the 'ambgious declaration/usage' error.

Comment: Looks like you have some common/shared rules in Project B and you would like to use them in Projects A and C. If this is the case, then you have to optimize your model to have the rule set parameters accordingly for each rule project else since the parameters/verbalization is the same for the parameters/local variables, there will be errors. I think the errors might go away when the verbalization is changed for the parameters/variables but still your might need to optimize your model for better design to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Yes, I am reusing the XOM and hence common voc for all the 3 projects. Will change and let you know in a day's time. Thanks